# Where to download D7000 Firmware version 1.04?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, firmware

I am looking to downgrade my D7000. I am only able to find version 1.05, to my knowledge. It is somewhat confusing, but I don't believe I am able to find 1.04. Does anyone have a reputable and/or reliable source for a D7000 version 1.04 firmware file?

Comment: IMHO you can't downgrade firmware (even if you get version 1.04)

Comment: As with every other time this question gets asked here: _why_ are you trying to downgrade your firmware?

Comment: I'm a photographer in a country with very limited resources and I own a Nikon camera. As it's not nearly what I need, and I have quite limited resources, I do have to work on things on my own at times because there's not much made for places and people that still use old devices, work in strange conditions, and have very little resources for the gear that I ideally need for my work.

Comment: Please describe which option will be "improved" if you donwgrade your firmware.

Comment: I happen to be both a scientist and a programmer and I have modiified my software in the past, and other technical fixes, repairs, etc. It's far too much to get into, but the unfortunate reality is that even if I did send my camera abroad to have repairs, for instance, it way outweighs the potential harm of losing a warranty, as considering how much I earn, how critical my camera is for my work, my limited options for earning, so I really can't even afford to send my gear off for repairs, as there are no repair techs here.

Comment: Additionally - I have downraded my firmware in the past. If this is not the case for a D7500, then, fair, but that sadly does reflect what seems like Nikon, and many other company's departure from making products that are usable, modifiable, and reparable by people who live in conditions that make it prohibitive to take the options thjey present - more expensive gear, etc. etc.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I thought the same thing for years, but there are ways to get around that, at least with Canon cameras. One way is to load the older firmware version on a memory card, insert it in the camera and begin the firmware update selection process. Proceed to the point where you select the firmware version on the card, then **before** you actually press the button to begin the firmware update (which is when you'd get a message that the version you're attempting to load is older than the current version), open the battery door and remove/replace the battery.

Comment: Point of clarification: Are you looking for D7000 firmware version A:1.04/B:1.05 (which, as far as I can tell is the most recent update) or firmware version A:1.03/B:1.04?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if your camera is a Nikon D7000 **A** or **B** version.

Follow the [link](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/22.html) for the download.

In the above link, depending on whether your camera is ver-A or ver-B, the firmware will automatically upgrade. Unfortunately, for ver-A cameras there is no option of 1.05, and for ver-B cameras, there is no option of 1.04.
(At least not that I know of.)

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely chance would be to join discussion groups dedicated to Nikon or even the Nikon D7000 at sites such as DP Review, on Flickr (do they still even have such groups?), Fred Miranda, etc. and ask the members there if anyone had a saved copy of the firmware version you are seeking.

If someone does have the file you're looking for you would need to get them to send it to you. Then you would need to weigh the risk of someone you do not know sending you a piece of possibly malicious software against the possible benefit of rolling your camera back to an older firmware version.